# What does it mean initialize to static struct definition with memset() set zero;?

Tags: c

I have reading some example code on C language from ON Semiconductor. So I have saw like this structure definition in header file:

```
typedef struct //that is example structure
{

    uint16_t features;

    bool blt;

    const struct anotherstruct *structinfo;
} name;
```

So there is the definition on .c file and then using like this in `foo()` function with `memset`:

```
static name lastname;

   foo()
   {
        memset(&lastname,0,sizeof(name ))
        lastname.features=23;
        lastname.structinfo=info; //there isn't assigned any value for blt.But there will be...(maybe ı am thinking this is the reason...)
    }
```

I have got some searching on this site and I know already, static definitions equal to zero. So why ON Semiconductor set to 0 `lastname` in addition?

`DP:foo()` function has called just once by designer. So that can't be reset function because this structure definition `lastname` used first in `foo()` function

Comment: I take the `lastnane` as a typo...

Comment: blt is false since it is memset to 0 (which is false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say by just looking at the short code pieces you have provided.

- You are correct that static variables are zero initialized, so there are strictly speaking no reason to zero them before using them.
- However, in real environments, it can be a good idea to not assume things. It's quite possible that this is just a "better safe than sorry".
- It can also be a reset function. That is, it is called more than once. If it's not called more than once, that can still be the original intention.
- A similar to the situation above can be that the reset function was written because there had been some code modifying `lastname` that has been removed, and then they forgot to remove `foo`.
- One more option is that the programmer don't know that static variables are zeroed on initialization, or just forgot. Don't assume that all code you find has a valid reason for looking the way it does.
- There is also a small chance that the programmer is tired of having to explain that static variables are zeroed and that globals are static to other programmers.
- Another (however unlikely) reason is that the programmer discovered a bug in the compiler, and this was a workaround.

It's impossible for us to figure out what another programmer thought when they wrote the code. Especially if we only have a small piece of the codebase. If you really want to know in this particular case, ask the author of the code.

Comment: You might like to add the case that `foo()` is called more than once.

Comment: I have to apology for this.But foo() function has called just once by designer.So that can't be reset function because this structure definition "lastname" used first in foo() function

Comment: @KaruF maybe it was originally intended to be a reset function, but the original author changed their mind. Only the programmer(s) who wrote that code can know why the `memset()` is there (and maybe even they don't remember). In the end, the only thing that matters is that your assumptions are correct, and the `memset()` is indeed not necessary in this function.

Comment: That's OK for me @FelixG . I am going to close this question in my mind :) Thanks for all answers...

Comment: @KaruF Then please mark the answer that fits best in your eyes.

Answer (score 3):

It means the binary representation of the struct will be all `0`'s, it seems the `foo()` function resets it to those values.

```
memset(&lastname,0,sizeof(name ))
lastname.features=23;
lastname.structinfo=info;
```

Comment: Yeah, but question is why is it needed, since the variable has a static storage already?

Comment: The author of `foo` is not assuming there are not other code paths that will change the members of `lastname` before `foo` is called.

Comment: I aggree with @SouravGhosh. Why we need to set 0 in addition?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers it can be added that in some certified safety critical applications there is general mistrust of operations performed by non-certified start up code, as oposed to operations performed by certified code produced in-house. (Btw I opposed this policy on a number of reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the bss is cleared by startup code. Some free-standing C environments - especially in the context of embedded systems - choose to not initialize the bss for performance reasons. It is necessary to explicitly zero static variables then.

See for example the Texas Instruments TMS320C6000:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru187o/spru187o.pdf (Section 6.10)

> The
>   ANSI/ISO
>   C
>   standard
>   specifies
>   that
>   global
>   (extern)
>   and
>   static
>   variables
>   without
>   explicit
>   initializations
>   must
>   be
>   initialized
>   to
>   0
>   before
>   the
>   program
>   begins
>   running.
>   This
>   task
>   is
>   typically
>   done
>   when
>   the
>   program
>   is
>   loaded.
>   Because
>   the
>   loading
>   process
>   is
>   heavily
>   dependent
>   on
>   the
>   specific
>   environment
>   of
>   the
>   target
>   application
>   system,
>   the
>   compiler
>   itself
>   makes
>   no
>   provision
>   for
>   preinitializing
>   variables
>   at
>   run
>   time.
>   It
>   is
>   up
>   to
>   your
>   application
>   to
>   fulfill
>   this
>   requirement.

Comment: So we can say that "whichever compiler ı have using ON Semiconductor IDE, compiler doesn't set 0 to value for static variables..." . Or like as on TI documents ; compiler doesn't have to this but programmer yes...